# How to ask a shop assistant if the shop has already started servicing?

Tags: word-choice

I do not know what would be the best way of saying this:

Suppose you walk into a shop and you notice there is not a single customer in the shop. So you cannot be sure if the shop has already started its business for the day. How can you ask the staff?

Can we say-

> Have you started servicing?

or,

> Are you open now or sth ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, Sahand. The sister site, ELL, deals with basic questions like this. Though 'Have you started serving?' and 'Are you open?' said with a smile should get you through until you can repost.

Comment: Hi @Sahand, welcome to ELU. I think with basic questions like this you should ask on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), where you'll probably get better answers more targeted to non-native speakers.

Comment: @Sahand:  I agree with the others that you might enjoy English Language Learners more.  I have edited your question a bit so the style sounds more like that of a native speaker.  I did this in an effort to help you to learn, not because the question was unreadable.  Good luck with your studies.

Comment: Judging from the time it often takes to find a member of staff in a department store, I sometimes wonder if they are open at 2.00 in the afternoon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Are you open (yet)?** would be the typical way to ask this in American English.

It will be perceived as polite, and will be understood immediately.

Comment: Thanks @David, is it typical to ask such a question. I mean if a native faces the same situation what will they normally say?

Comment: @Sahand Without question.  You have my word as a native speaker of American English.